# Using cancan with gems controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First of all sorry for my bad english.
I've installed cancan and bigbluebutton_rails,
https://github.com/mconf/bigbluebutton_rails.
The gem bigbluebutton_rails has some models and controllers, for
example has bigbluebutton/servers_controller.rb.
This controller has some actions like create, join, authorize, etc.
I want that only users with role admin can create.
What can I do?
I need to put load_and_authorize_resource in bigbluebutton/servers_controller.rb?
But it is inside a gem and I think it is not recommended to modify gems code.

Answer (score 2):

They have a page for integrating with cancan: https://github.com/mconf/bigbluebutton_rails/wiki/How-to%3A-Integrate-with-CanCan

But ummm, it hasn't yet been written...

So... They also have a page for integrating with Devise: https://github.com/mconf/bigbluebutton_rails/wiki/How-to%3A-Integrate-with-Devise which has been written, and so extrapolating from that the accepted way would be to inherit the `Bigbluebutton::ServersController`.

How about creating a custom servers controller as follows:

```
class CustomServersController < Bigbluebutton::ServersController
  load_and_authorize_resource!
end
```

Comment: Yes I think creating a custom controller is the only way, I must change all references to original controller in the code.

Comment: It does look like that's the way to go yes, sorry I couldn't point you towards something easier!

Answer (score 0):

In ruby you can reopen classes, so put some code in /config/initializers/bigbluebutton.rb that says

```
require 'bigbluebutton'

class Bigbluebutton::ServersController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource!

  # you also have to overwrite this method so the @server loaded
  # by CanCan is not overwritten by Bigbluebutton
  def find_server
    @server ||= BigbluebuttonServer.find_by_param(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementing Sam Peacey's answer, now BigbluebuttonRails has a (rather simple) wiki page describing how to integrate it with CanCan: [https://github.com/mconf/bigbluebutton_rails/wiki/How-to:-Integrate-with-CanCan](https://github.com/mconf/bigbluebutton_rails/wiki/How-to%3a-Integrate-with-CanCan)

You can also use the application Mconf-Web (https://github.com/mconf/mconf-web) as an example. The version currently in the branch `branch-v2` (https://github.com/mconf/mconf-web/tree/branch-v2) uses CanCan, Devise and BigbluebuttonRails, all working together.